# How to run different queries on Spring Batch in various databases that are in different locations?

Tags: database-connection, spring-batch

Using Spring Batch , I would like to query multiple databases , which are in different locations and with
Similar structures but with  different names columns.

Comment: What is the mechanism you want to indicate where the job is pointing?  Job parameters?  Properties file?  Use Spring XD and use deployment options?

Comment: well, what I have to do is:
   - Read various relational databases that are in various locations,
  - Processing the collected data,
  - Insert them in a single table in a local relational database.

Comment: What I'm getting at is you need to communicate to job instance A that it needs to talk to database A and job instance B that it needs to talk to database B.  How do you wish to do that?  Once you identify how you want to communicate that message, I can recommend how to do it.  For the record, Spring XD already has a job that has a similar behavior (jdbchdfs) so you may want to look at Spring XD and that job...

Comment: in a bad mood, what I want to do is:  
    select all in table 'employees' from database 'Alabama' then insert all into table 'employees' from database USA.  
    select all in table 'employees' from database 'Arizona' then insert all into table 'employees' from database USA.  
    select all in table 'employees' from database 'Colorado' then insert all into table 'employees' from database USA.  
    select all in table 'employees' from database 'Idaho' then insert all into table 'employees' from database USA.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write two separate jobs for two databases and dump into same desired table ?